# I need to modify the boilerplate login. I need only the email is required to enter

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am starting with the use of Boilerplate and I would like to know if it is possible to customize the login that comes by default, for example: I need that only the email is required to enter and not ask for a password.

Comment: ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET MVC 5?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible by default.

But you can modify the login action on the Account controller and force always the same password to all of the users. The line is :

```
var loginResult = await _logInManager.LoginAsync(usernameOrEmailAddress, password, tenancyName);
```

Of course do the same on the user creation.